# Speed up a Numba parallel loop on a very large function for JIT - using parallel_diagnostics output - guidance requested

Tags: python, optimization, parallel-processing, numba, jit

It seems all the StackExchange posts for Numba have very simple functions.  In my case, the function under examination is 70 lines of actual code.  So the optimization of the function is very difficult - I'm not really sure where to start.  I'm just asking for tips on what to look at so I can profile a large function with Numba (or other tools?) and improve it.  In its current state, it looks quite strange as the goal was to make Numba parallel work, rather than optimizing it.  This is a real world example of taking code someone else wrote, converting all the functions over to being Numba compatible (which meant merging 7 functions into 1), then attempting to optimize it as much as possible (to be done next)...

I setup a GitHub repo with the function I'm examining called `Basket_price`, along with the parallel.diagnostics(level=4) output here: https://github.com/mattslezak-shell/numba_function.  Inputs are stored in a file called `test.npy` which will allow the function to run on real data (it will load when you run `test_numba.py`).  If I run the test_numba.py in an IPython instance, I can later run `Basket_price.parallel_diagnostics(level=4)`, which is how I generated the output file `parallel_diagnostics.txt`.

Now, it seems all the tests performed by Numba in parallelization take a long time (>15 seconds), then they are cached and become quite fast.  I realize the normal approach would be to target the areas that are serial and rewrite them to be parallel.  Now there are some things that SHOULD be parallel, but aren't, but I'll notate after the diagnostics file excerpt:

Here's a sample of the output generated that seem to be automatically done when an `@nb.njit(parallel=True)` is passed:

```
----------------------------- Before Optimisation ------------------------------
Parallel region 0:
+--9 (parallel)
+--2 (parallel)


Parallel region 1:
+--22 (parallel)
   +--12 (parallel)
   +--13 (parallel)
   +--14 (parallel)
   +--15 (parallel)
   +--3 (parallel)


Parallel region 2:
+--16 (parallel)
+--4 (parallel)


Parallel region 3:
+--17 (parallel)
+--5 (parallel)


Parallel region 4:
+--25 (parallel)
   +--24 (parallel)
      +--7 (parallel)


Parallel region 5:
+--19 (parallel)
+--20 (parallel)


Parallel region 6:
+--21 (parallel)
+--23 (parallel)


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------ After Optimisation ------------------------------
Parallel region 0:
+--9 (parallel, fused with loop(s): 2)


Parallel region 1:
+--22 (parallel)
   +--12 (serial)
   +--13 (serial)
   +--14 (serial)
   +--15 (serial, fused with loop(s): 3)


Parallel region 2:
+--16 (parallel, fused with loop(s): 4)


Parallel region 3:
+--17 (parallel, fused with loop(s): 5)


Parallel region 4:
+--25 (parallel)
   +--24 (serial)
      +--7 (serial)


Parallel region 5:
+--19 (parallel, fused with loop(s): 20)


Parallel region 6:
+--21 (parallel, fused with loop(s): 23)
```

So using logic, it tells me regions 1 and 4 it was unable to parallelize some of the inside code, so they were kept serial (as Jerome pointed out, that's likely fine - the outer loop runs in parallel).  It was not obvious to me that it is fine to have an outer loop run in parallel with portions running inside the loop in serial.

The profiler isn't all that helpful other than telling me "it's parallel" or "it's not parallel" rather than time spent in each step.  This guide for Numba is pretty long and hard to follow: https://numba.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/stable/pdf/

I'm unsure of where else to focus any of my efforts, so suggestions are welcome.  A lot of this code is written in quite unusual ways because I had to use functions that would mimic unsupported NumPy functions so Numba could operate on it.

Any optimization / profiling advice is appreciated!

Comment: I am confused since It seems you assume that parallel loops containing parallel loop are somehow "more parallel" than basic parallel loops. AFAIK, this is not the case. It is just useful to provide more parallelism and work at a smaller granularity. The former is only interesting if there is not enough parallelism yet (otherwise this is useless). The later can be useful to design more cache-friendly algorithm but I do not think this is currently your focus. By the ways the code is quite big and the question is not explicitly stated and rather unclear to me. Can you clarify this?

Comment: Thank you @JérômeRichard - it was not clear to me that those loops marked parallel with serial inner loops were still running in parallel.  Really I am just looking for ways to optimize this ugly code base further than what I've done already.

Comment: Ok. Then I advise you to spot the slowest part of the code by profiling it (manually since Numba does not support profiling tools AFAIK) and then try to optimize the work done in the loop dependently of the parallelism. If you plan to ask further question on the code, please make reproducible example and focus on a specific part of the code so we can better help you. By the way, be careful about using parallel loops as this can introduce race conditions / bugs. For example I find the loop `for i in nb.prange(findtrue.shape[0]) [...] break` suspiciously wrong. Are you sure this is supported?

Comment: Good advice @JérômeRichard yes I realize that posting a giant code base makes analysis difficult.  And good eyes there that loop shouldn't be marked as parallel since it's actually finding the first element that is true in an array, and if done in parallel, it could find a random true element that is not the first one.

Comment: Speaking of profiling @JérômeRichard - how would you advise doing it for a large function like this?  I usually put a bunch of timeit timers all over the code, but that's not really efficient.  If you know of a better way please let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have nothing much better than putting some `time.time()` calls in the code or timeit magic operators. I found [that](https://numba-how-to.readthedocs.io/en/latest/profiling.html) in the doc that can be quite useful so to better automatise this operation (and not pollute the code with many timing calls). Good luck.